# How to check if a specific xml node is empty & remove it?

Tags: sql, xml

```
DECLARE @XmlDoc XML

SET @XmlDoc = '<root>
   <emp>
      <name>John</name>
      <salary>22140</salary>
   </emp>
   <emp>
      <name>Walter</name>
      <salary />
   </emp>
   <emp>
      <salary />
   </emp>
</root>'
```

I want to check if salary node inside emp is empty or not, if its empty delete that node. Below is what I've tried. It deletes the entire emp tag inside of just the salary tag.

```
SET @XmlDoc.modify('delete //root/emp[salary = ""]')
```

Current Output:

```
<root>
  <emp>
    <name>John</name>
    <salary>22140</salary>
  </emp>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root>
  <emp>
      <name>John</name>
      <salary>22140</salary>
  </emp>
  <emp>
      <name>Walter</name>
  </emp>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current XPath is addressing the `emp` element and testing whether or not the `salary` computed text value is empty. If you want to address the `salary` element, then change the XPath to add a step, and then test it's own value in the predicate:

```
SET @XmlDoc.modify('delete //root/emp/salary[. = ""]')
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggested answers works but if we have a namespace to the root node then it doesn't work. eg:  <root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/something/">...</root> Do you know how to skip the namespace check?

Comment: You can declare that namespace and use the prefix in your xpath: i.e. `//s:root/s:emp/s:salary[.=""]` or match generically on the local-name() and ignore the namespace: `//*[local-name()="root"]/*[local-name() = "emp"]/*[local-name()="salary" and .=""]` (and you can also add a check for the namespace in the predicate with `namespace-uri()="w3c.org/something/"`, but if you care about the namespace then it's much better and easier to just declare the namespace and use the namespace-prefix in your XPath).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

Notable pouints:

- There is no need to use //. It is very inefficient, and will traverse
  the entire XML.
- XPath predicate `[not(text())]` is a better way to check for an empty
  text node.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @XmlDoc XML =
N'<root xmlns="w3.org/something/">
   <emp>
      <name>John</name>
      <salary>22140</salary>
   </emp>
   <emp>
      <name>Walter</name>
      <salary />
   </emp>
   <emp>
      <salary />
   </emp>
</root>';

SET @XmlDoc.modify('declare default element namespace "w3.org/something/";
    delete /root/emp/salary[not(text())]');

-- test
SELECT @XmlDoc;
```

**Output**

```
<root xmlns="w3.org/something/">
  <emp>
    <name>John</name>
    <salary>22140</salary>
  </emp>
  <emp>
    <name>Walter</name>
  </emp>
  <emp />
</root>
```